# How do i send ads1115 data over spi to master arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, c, string

I am trying to send ADS 1115 data which is connected with Arduino mega_1 over I2C and arduino Mega_1 is connected with arduino Mega_0 over SPI.
Arduino Mega_1 is act as a slave and send ADS 1115 data to master device..
I think my whole setup is working but i want to received actual data of ADS 1115 on master Arduino
Here is screenshots of results of my code[image]

**master**

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
  Serial.println ();

  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);  // ensure SS stays high for now

  // Put SCK, MOSI, SS pins into output mode
  // also put SCK, MOSI into LOW state, and SS into HIGH state.
  // Then put SPI hardware into Master mode and turn SPI on
  SPI.begin ();

  // Slow down the master a bit
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);

}  // end of setup

byte transferAndWait (const byte what)
{
  byte a = SPI.transfer (what);
  delayMicroseconds (20);
  return a;
} // end of transferAndWait

void loop (void)
{
byte a;

  // enable Slave Select
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);    

  transferAndWait ('a');  // add command
a=transferAndWait (0);


  // disable Slave Select
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  Serial.println ("results:");
  Serial.println (a);

  delay (1000);  // 1 second delay 
}  // end of loop
```

**slave**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>
int out_buf;
int adc0;

// Adafruit_ADS1115 ads;  /* Use this for the 16-bit version */
Adafruit_ADS1015 ads;
// what to do with incoming data
volatile byte command = 0;
void ss_falling ()
{
  command = 0;
} 
void setup (void)
{
 ads.begin();
 Serial.begin(9600);  
 //ads.startComparator_SingleEnded(0, 1000);
// have to send on master in, *slave out*
 pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

// turn on SPI in slave mode
 SPCR |= _BV(SPE);

 // turn on interrupts
 SPCR |= _BV(SPIE);
 attachInterrupt (0, ss_falling, FALLING);

}

// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
 byte c = SPDR;

  switch (command)
  {
  // no command? then this is the command
  case 0:
    command = c;
    SPDR = 0;
    break;

  // add to incoming byte, return result
  case 'a':
    SPDR = out_buf; // add 15
    break;

  } // end of switch

}  // end of interrupt service routine (ISR) SPI_STC_vect


void loop (void)
{
adc0 = ads.readADC_SingleEnded(0);
Serial.print("AIN0: "); Serial.println(adc0);

out_buf=adc0;
//int buff = atoi(out_buf);
Serial.print("AIN1: "); Serial.println(out_buf);
delay(1000);
 }
```

i am sending 1570 but on Master side i received 35 i think ADS data is of 16 bits i.e 2 bytes and SPI received only 1 byte at a time i am stuck here please help me.
Thank you in Advance

example
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved now, thanks to the almighty. I did few changed in code as:
1. Converted the received int type data from ADS to Char.
2. Stored it in an Array, to form a string.

Here is my Modified Slave Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>
Adafruit_ADS1015 ads;
void setup (void)
{
ads.begin();
 Serial.begin(9600);
  // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= bit(SPE);

  // turn on interrupts
  SPCR |= bit(SPIE);
}  // end of setup

char buf[20];
volatile int pos;
volatile bool active;


// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
  byte c = SPDR;

  if (c == 1)  // starting new sequence?
    {
    active = true;
    pos = 0;
    SPDR = buf [pos++];   // send first byte
    return;
    }

  if (!active)
    {
    SPDR = 0;
    return;
    }

  SPDR = buf [pos];
  if (buf [pos] == 0 || ++pos >= sizeof (buf))
    active = false;
}  // end of interrupt service routine (ISR) SPI_STC_vect

void loop (void)
{
int adc0=0;
adc0 = ads.readADC_SingleEnded(0);
itoa(adc0,buf,10);
Serial.print("AIN1: "); Serial.println(buf);
delay(500);
}  // end of loop
```

**On Master side**

We are receiving string by sending one dummy value at a time.
Here is modified master code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
  Serial.println ("Starting");

  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);  // ensure SS stays high for now

  // Put SCK, MOSI, SS pins into output mode
  // also put SCK, MOSI into LOW state, and SS into HIGH state.
  // Then put SPI hardware into Master mode and turn SPI on
  SPI.begin ();

  // Slow down the master a bit
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);

}  // end of setup

void loop (void)
{
  char buf [20];

  // enable Slave Select
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);    
  SPI.transfer (1);   // initiate transmission
  for (int pos = 0; pos < sizeof (buf) - 1; pos++)
    {
    delayMicroseconds (15);
    buf [pos] = SPI.transfer (0);
    if (buf [pos] == 0)
      {
      break;
      }
    }

  buf [sizeof (buf) - 1] = 0;  // ensure terminating null

  // disable Slave Select
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  Serial.print ("We received: ");
  Serial.println (buf);

  delay (500); 
}  // end of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing SPI slave mode is a little more tricky than you may think.  The most important thing to remember is that it's not a "Give me X" -> "Ok, here is X" kind of protocol.  It's actually a "Here's X" <=> "Here's Y" protocol.

That is, at the same time that the master sends X to the slave, the slave sends "Y" to the master.

The way you have it is that the master sends "a" as a command and discards what it receives.  The slave remembers that "a" as the "command". Then the master sends 0, and remembers what it receives. The slave receives that 0 and thinks "Ah, I got the command last time, so it must want the value" and queues up the value to be sent the next time a transaction occurs.  That then gets thrown away, since that occurs when the next "command" is sent.

You need to be a little more cunning, and implement a finite state machine to work out where in the stream you are.

- When SS falls set a "byte counter" to 0.
- When a byte is received examine the "byte counter":

  - Byte 0: If it's an "a" then place the first byte of the value in SPDR.
  - Byte 1: Place the second byte of the value in SPDR
  - Byte 3: Do nothing (or place 0 in SPDR)
- Increment the byte counter

So the transaction goes something like this (1570 is 0x622 in hex, and I choose "little endian" since the AVR is naturally little endian):

```
Master Sends        Slave Queues          Master Receives
'a'                 0x22                  Rubbish
0                   0x06                  0x22
0                   0x00                  0x06

'a'                 0x22                  0x00
0                   0x06                  0x22
0                   0x00                  0x06
```

The important thing to remember is that the master receives what the slave queued *on the next transfer*.

Comment: My SPI communication is working fine because i also tried addition and subtraction between master and slave and the result was "ok "

Comment: If your spi communication were working fine you wouldn't be here asking us for help...

Comment: dude read this lines "i am sending 1570 which is a ads1115 data but on Master side i received 35 i think ADS data is of 16 bits i.e 2 bytes and SPI received only 1 byte at a time." SPI is ok to me.... i think there is something missing like byte to char conversion or split 16 bit adc data into 8 bits and thn sent to master that is my real problem.

Comment: 35 has no relation to 1570. The closest you could be receiving would be 34 (0x22). Fixing your code in the way I specify not only fixes the mess you made of the sending system, but also fixes the 16-bit issue. Oh, and make your out_buf volatile. Also the out_buf should be "captured" at the point you either queue the first byte, or when SS falls.

Comment: i added two more screenshots in which i send 10 and in return i received 20  "20=10 +10"

Comment: It's pure chance that *sometimes* you happen to receive a result you *think* is right. It isn't You're receiving *old* results from *previous* transactions that *never got sent*.

Comment: ok if i am doing wrong thn what is the right way to send ads data to master arduino by using spi

Comment: How I detailed in my answer.